# Angular 2 services subscribed twice

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http

I just start first project with Angular 2 and I've trouble with services.

I've an http service called when submitting a form, but when I submit the form, the http request is executed twice.

**login.component.html**

```
<form method="post" (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="input input--block input--text-center" required >
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="passord" class="input input--block input--text-center" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Connect" class="btn btn--block">
</form>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
login() {
    this.service.login(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .subscribe( res => {
            if (res == null) {
                alert("Fail");
            } else {
                res.password = null;
                this.user = res;
                alert("Welcome "+this.user.firstname+"!");
        }
    });
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
login(email:string, password:string): Observable<User> {
    let CryptoJS = require("cryptojs");
    let sha512 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA512.create();
    sha512.update(password);
    password = sha512.finalize().toString();
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/user/login`, 
        {email: email.trim(), password: password.trim()}, 
        {headers: this.headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I added some `console.log("test");` to check which method is called twice and it appears that there is no method called twice, just the HTTP request that I can see in the network console of the web browser

Comment: Is one of the requests `OPTIONS` and the other one `POST` ?

Comment: One is a options request which checks for the methods in server. then the actual request is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing `OPTIONS` and `POST` requests with a double `POST` request

`OPTIONS` requests are essential for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are permitted to read that information using a web browser.  Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP **OPTIONS** request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method. Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials" (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with requests.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: You're right, the first request is OPTIONS and the second one is POST